# Jogo da forca em C

Tags: c

Boa noite amigos, espero que estejam bem.

O problema em que preciso de ajuda é um código bem simples(jogo da forca), porém, como sou novato em programação e estou aprendendo C não estou identificando onde exatamente está o erro. O programa executa tudo normal, o problema é que após eu digitar a primeira letra da palavra o programa tenta fazer a leitura e termina o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
char palavra[21];
char resposta[21];
char letra[21];
char espaco[21]="*";
char erradas[21];
char tamanho;
int tentativas=5, acertos=0, erros=5;
int cont, corretas;


printf(">>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<\n");
printf(">>> JOGO DA FORCA <<< \n");
printf(">>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<\n");

printf("\nDigite a palavra que deseja: ");
gets(palavra);


for (cont =0; cont<strlen(palavra); cont++)
    espaco[cont]='*';
    tamanho=strlen(palavra);

    while (erros > 0)
    {
        corretas =0;
        printf("\n%s\n", espaco);
        printf("\nDigite uma letra: ");
        gets(letra);
        printf("\n\tLetra digitada: %s\n", erros);

        for (cont =0; cont <strlen(palavra); cont++)
        {
            if (letra[0] == palavra[cont])
            {
                espaco[cont] = palavra[cont];
                corretas++;
                acertos++;
            }
        }

        if (corretas ==0);
        {
            tentativas--;
            if (tentativas ==0)
            {
                printf("\nVoce Faleceu\n");
                printf("\nA palavra era %s\n", palavra);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nVoce errou uma letra, ainda tem %d chances", tentativas);
                erradas[erros] = letra[0];
                erros++;
            }



        while (acertos == tamanho)
                {
                    printf("\nAcertou a palavra\n");
                    break;
                }
                if (letra == palavra)
                {
                    printf("\nAcertou uma letra\n");
                }
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Creio que aqui: `if (corretas ==0);` não tenha este `;` pois senão você estará executando o comando nulo caso a condição seja verdadeira. Não entendi este `while (acertos == tamanho) {` pois se for verdadeiro você não modifica as variáveis dentro do loop e dá um break, não bastaria um `if`?

Answer (score 0):

É uma forte suspeita, então vou colocar já como resposta.

Arrays de caracteres em C devem ser sempre terminadas em `\0` (para seu conhecimento isso representa o caracter de valor `0` na tabela ASCII, note que isso é diferente do caracter que representa o número `"0"` que você digita no teclado, que tem outro valor).

Inclusive essas arrays devem ser dimensionadas tendo em mente um espaço extra para esse caracter `\0`.

Isso é necessário porque algumas funções como a `strlen()` que você chamou no código dependem disso, pois percorrem o array até encontrar um `\0` e parar.

Se não encontram, continuam avançando além do tamanho do array e invadem memória ocupada por outros dados, o que pode causar erro no programa e mesmo terminá-lo prematuramente.

Por isso, verifique se o `gets()` acrescenta o `\0` ao final da cadeia de caracteres que foi digitada. Eu acredito que não. Então o que deve estar acontecendo é a cadeia que foi digitada estar quebrando a `strlen()`.

Você terá que buscar uma alternativa então, acrescentar esse caracter na mão ou encontrar uma outra função que o acrescente automaticamente na digitação da palavra.

Comment: De acordo com https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html: "The gets() function shall read bytes from the standard input stream, stdin, into the array pointed to by s, until a <newline> is read or an end-of-file condition is encountered. Any <newline> shall be discarded and a null byte shall be placed immediately after the last byte read into the array.". Não é recomendado o seu uso porque ela pode causar um overflow da área alocada sem relatar qualquer problema, é melhor utilizar `fgets` para limitar os caracteres lidos mas, eventualmente, terá que tratar o '\n' final

Answer (score 0):

**Entrando apenas no mérito do programa estar abortando sua execução**, o problema está na função `printf`, logo após o "preenchimento" da variável `letra`:

```
printf("\n\tLetra digitada: %s\n", erros);
```

Perceba que está usando [a formatação para valores que representam `string`s e não `int`s](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet/). Com isso, a função `printf` está recebendo um tipo diferente do que foi informado em sua formatação, resultando em um comportamento indefinido.

Basta mudar a formatação para o tipo `int`:

```
printf("\n\tLetra digitada: %i\n", erros);
```

Pois sua variável foi declarada como tendo seu tipo `int`:

```
int tentativas=5, acertos=0, erros=5;
```